# unable to assign value dynamically to TextInput using react native

Tags: react-native

In my scenario, while focus on TextInput i am moving to another scene using navigator (using push)there i populate list,in that list selecting one value that value should be populated to the previous scene of TextInput In this case I am unable to set the selected value to the previous scene of TextInput.

My code structure is

```
var FirstComponent = React.createClass({
     render:function(){
             return(<TextInput value="" placeholder="Enter value" onFocus={getData.bind(this)} />)
      }
})

function getData(ev){
var target = ev;
      this.props.navigator.push({
          id:'SecondComponent',
          name:'SecondComponent',
          target:target, 
       })
}
var SecondComponent = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
               return(<TouchableHighlight onPress={fillData.bind(this,target, self.props.navigator,selectedText)}><Text>sample</Text></TouchableHighlight>)
        }
});
function fillData(rootThis,nav,selectedText,ev){

     rootThis.value=selectedText;
     rootThis.nativeEvent.target = selectedText;
     rootThis.nativeEvent.target .text= selectedText; // Here ' rootThis ' is route object 'this'

//how to fill selectedText in FirstComponent TextInput value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to use bind anymore if you are just passing the default attribute returned from a component.

Anyway, I would do something like this:

```
first_component.js:


var FirstComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    value: ""
  },

  render:function(){
    return(
      <TextInput value={this.state.value} placeholder="Enter value" onFocus={this.moveToSecondComponent} >
    );
  },

  moveToSecondComponent: function() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: SecondComponent
      onSelect: this.popBackAndUpdate // This assumes you are using Navigator. If you are using NavigatorIOS, just wrap it in 'passprops'
    })
  },

  popBackAndUpdate: function(value) {
    this.setState({value: value});
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }

});


second_component.js:
var SecondComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.props.route.onSelect("new value")}}>
        <Text>sample</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>)
  }
});
```

This main point is that in the 2nd component you just pass the new value to the callback function and it will pop back the navigator.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thnks eyal83.in my case popBackAndUpdate function is outside the component here how can i get FirstComponent  this

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you explain?

Comment: ok.how can I define popBackAndUpdate function out side the component.

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. You should keep a function which is really "React oriented" in the component. You want your 'this' to be clear that it's the React component. If you need to reuse it in several places, you can create a mixin and just include it in your different components.

Comment: In my case mixin(because i am new to reactnative)  are not suitable.  Is it not possible to define popBackAndUpdate function out side the component.